# detected windows Shut down/Log Off/ Log On, in worker service .net 5

Tags: c#, worker

I'm using this code for .net framework and work correctly. But in .net 5 not work.
I want log status when windows log off or log in etc.

```
        public Worker()
        {
            CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
            CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
        }

      protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
        {
            switch (changeDescription.Reason)
            {
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon:
                    Console.WriteLine("System Log On Time: \t " + DateTime.Now);
                    break;
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogoff:
                    Console.WriteLine("System Log Off Time: \t " + DateTime.Now);
                    break;
                case SessionChangeReason.RemoteConnect:
                    Console.WriteLine("System Remote Connect Time: \t " + DateTime.Now);
                    break;
                case SessionChangeReason.RemoteDisconnect:
                    Console.WriteLine("System Remote Disconnect Time: \t " + DateTime.Now);
                    break;
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionLock:
                    Console.WriteLine("System Locked Time: \t" + DateTime.Now);
                    break;
                case SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock:                    
                    Console.WriteLine("System Unlocked Time: \t " + DateTime.Now);
                    break; 
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `But in .net 5 not work` isn't very descriptive for us to understand your issue. Have you tried stepping through the code, does `OnSessionChange` even get hit?

Comment: No, OnSessionChange  don't hit

Comment: How was this method overridden? What is the full name of the base class for the class with this method?